# Two Data-Parent (ID wrapped in ID) and Bootstrap does not work

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have to place my accordion in a `<div style="display:none;">` and then div which also have an id tag ( `<div id="outerid">` ) because I am popping up my accordion by tooltip.js, where `<div id="outerid">` defines the target for tooltip.js. 
My tabs
( `<a class="accordion-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" onmouseover="this.click();" href="#tab2">HOVER ME FOR TAB 2</a>` ) works fine out of `<div style="display:none;">`, even within `<div id="outerid">`. As soon as i place `<div id="outerid">` with  in `<div style="display:none;">` the following happening.

My accordion shows up beautifully when you hover over outerid's target,
but the tabs in the accordion do not work.

(NOTE: If I have an external target e.g href="http://helloworld.com in that case,the tabs work, but with anchor target e.g href="#tab2", they don't.

Anyone has any idea why is that?

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="outerid">
        <div id="accordion">
            <div class="accordion-group panel">
                <a class="accordion-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" onmouseover="this.click();" href="#tab1">
                                                HOVER FOR TAB 1
                                             </a>
                <div id="tab1" class="collapse in">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                        <p>HELLO WORLD 1st</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group panel">
                <a class="accordion-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" onmouseover="this.click();" href="#tab2">
                                               HOVER ME FOR TAB 2
                                             </a>
                <div id="tab2" class="collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                        <p>HELLO WORLD 2nd </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group panel">
                <a class="accordion-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" onmouseover="this.click();" href="#tab3">
                                               HOVER ME FOR TAB3
                                             </a>
                <div id="tab3" class="collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                        <p>HELLO WORLD 3rd</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!---End Accordion---->
    </div>
    <!--- Outerid end---->
</div><!---End Non Display--->
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nvonog3x/1/

Comment: So, I do not understand. If I place it in my page it works. But when i want the accordion as a tooltip and using tooltip.js to display the panel the tabs stop working. So, I figured it is due to the  '<div id="outerid">'. Could it be because they are located in '<div style="display:none;">'?